# Cartoon about fighter pilots in 2000s?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember a cartoon about futuristic plane fighters. The cartoon was launched around the year 2000, it is in computer graphics not in classical drawing.

There are two girls in the group, one of the guys can turn into a beast, like a werewolf and had special googles not like the rest of the characters.

The bad guy had a giant robot in some episodes and in one episode a girl from the group is kidnapped and if the group shot the bad guy, she has a lot of pain.

Also in another episode they use cd as a countermeasures for heat seeking missiles.

This cartoon show was in Spain.

Comment: *Storm Hawks* is a partial match, but no transforming into a beast.

Comment: Did you watch it in Spain, was it a Spanish cartoon, or was it set in Spain? Just wanting to clarify the last line :)

Comment: i watch the cartoon in Spain but is not settled in Spain nor from Spain, The cartoon isn´t Storm Hawks, the cgi is less polished.

Comment: Huh. I wonder if perhaps the CD was based off of the urban legend that hanging a CD from your rearview mirror will fool radar guns.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're talking about MetaJets? It's got some cgi and it's about fighter pilots, although it was 2009/2010

Comment: Does this match the other details given in the description, like the guy who could turn into a beast, or the bad guy with a giant robot?

Comment: No, this series is in  2010, the series i asked is about the year 2000 more or less between 1998 and 2002 but could be before but based on the cgi i doub it,